# Javascript - Removing all side effects from an external script

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to remove all side effects created from a third party script, without concretely knowing what they are?

Simple toy example:

A script is loaded via a `script` tag, it created a new DOM element, and also attaches some data to the `window` object.

My application now wants to remove anything this script has created/added to the browser.

Is it possible to delete all the effects?

Comment: It seems that in general this task would be equivalent to the halting problem (think of side effects in non-terminating execution paths), thus: no.  Assuming terminating code, how would you handle statements that depend on user inputs (includes data queried over the net) ? You might have to enumerate over potentially very large domains in your sanitizing code. Side effect code my hinge on trigegring local structures, think of complex dom selectors. So the check will probably be  inefficent in time and  space. Maybe you can resort to aggressive code pruning or case-by-case reasoning.

Comment: it seems we have a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here

Comment: @collapsar what about sandboxing and deleting the sandbox?

Comment: @ydennis: It seems you think about intercepting side effect calls or to supply some reference structure and compare it with the result of code potentially having side effects. Even if you manage one of these, you'd still have to cause the tested code to actually produce side effects. This might depend on very particular (meaning: rare) user input or context.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. The only way to «remove» all effects from a external script is not loading it in the first place. Even if you target all script elements and delete them, the code would have already been executed.

Comment: Are you sure, what if a load it in an iFrame? Or within some other code generated sandbox?

Comment: @ydennis If the code only affects structures within the iframe, we have the original problem. If it does affect structures outside the iframe, how do you make sure that these code portions do not cause side effects if you do not know the nature of said side effects in advance ?

Comment: @collapsar that is precisely my question - but it seems that it should be possible, even if not trivial.

Comment: An `<iframe>` is not a sandbox. Scripts inside iframes can use `window.top` to access and alter the main page. The answer to "Is it possible to remove all side effects created from a third party script" is **no**. You cannot undo code that has already been executed, but you can run scripts in a sandbox, if you find an API for that.

Comment: The closest would probably be some save state.